# Can't send form after dynamically reload that form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have problem with submit form in case when that form was dynamically reloaded. 
I will try to explain the situation:

I have form like this:

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="addForm">
  <input id="numer_listu" name="numer_listu" type="text" class="form-control">
  <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md pull-right">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> Dodaj
  </button>
</form>
```

And JavaScript:

```
$("#addForm").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    submitForm();
});
```

And this works fine. But when I want clear that form (it has more fields than my example) I use `$(".addPanelCont").load('inc/addPanel.php');` - it load clear form in `.addPanelCont` contener. And now `.submit()` doesn't work. After click `submit` page is reloaded.

I tried also:

```
$("#addForm").on('click', 'button#form-submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  submitForm();
});
```

But it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think `#addForm` is dynamically added too try:

```
$(".addPanelCont").on('click', 'button#form-submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  submitForm();
});
```